# Applying chain responsibility with IFilter

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have an interface `IFilter` and more types of filters: `Filter1`, `Filter2`, `Filter3`; that I want to call one after the other and if the result of one is empty, then I want to stop the process. For this I have thought of:

```
class FiltersSequence
{
private:
    std::vector< IFilter > m_filters;

public:
    FiltersSequence();
    ~FiltersSequence();

    /**/
    ObjectToFilter execute(const ObjectToFilter& objectToFilterIn);
};
```

With the implementations:

```
FiltersSequence::FiltersSequence()
{
    m_filters.push_back(Filter3());
    m_filters.push_back(Filter2());
    m_filters.push_back(Filter1());
}

FiltersSequence::~FiltersSequence() {}

ObjectToFilter FiltersSequence::execute(const ObjectToFilter& objectToFilterIn)
{
    ObjectToFilter filterResult = objectToFilterIn;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < m_filters.size(); i++)
    {
        filterResult = m_filters[i].execute();
        if (filterResult.isEmpty())
        {
            return filterResult;
        }
    }

    return filterResult;
}
```

It should be vector of pointers, because the filters are not all the same size; so I have changed to:

```
std::vector< std::shared_ptr< IFilter > > m_filters;
```

and

```
m_filters.push_back(std::shared_ptr< IFilter >(new FilterX()));
```

I thought of something like having a `map< std::string, IFilter >` for being sure that the sequence is in the order that I want. What do you think of this? Is it good enough? Or this is just making it more complicated and I need just to pay attention at `push_back`. BTW, is this going to call them in right order (1, 2, 3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Kumar have already mentioned, just keep it simple and use `std::vector`. It is a very efficient data structure since every element is stored next to each other in contiguous memory. This gives you great cache utilization for sequential access (which is what you do in the loop).

As for the ordering, right now you are doing

```
FiltersSequence::FiltersSequence()
{                                   // m_filters: {}
    m_filters.push_back(Filter3()); // m_filters: {Filter3}
    m_filters.push_back(Filter2()); // m_filters: {Filter3, Filter2}
    m_filters.push_back(Filter1()); // m_filters: {Filter3, Filter2, Filter1}
}
```

which is in *reverse* order since what you want is {Filter1, Filter2, Filter3}. You have to reverse the `push_back` calls to get the correct behaviour.

Also, you are overriding `filterResult` in every iteration

```
filterResult = m_filters[i].execute(); // filterResult is overriden.
```

Don't you mean to do something like

```
filterResult = m_filters[i].execute(filterResult);
```

instead? I don't have the signature of an `IFilter` so it is hard to know.

Beside those semantic issues, the code has good overall structure. Good job! I only have comments on the details. I'm going to assume that you use C++03 in the following:

- Drop the destructor `~FiltersSequence()`. Your compiler will automatically generate one for you which does the right thing.
- Break the loop instead. I.e.,

  ```
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < m_filters.size(); i++)
  {
      filterResult = m_filters[i].execute();
      if (filterResult.isEmpty()) break;
  }
  ```

  This simplifies the code and is semantically equivalent since the return statement in the bottom of the function is reached instead.
- Prefer pre-increment to post-increment. There is [no semantic difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706199/post-increment-and-pre-increment-within-a-for-loop-produce-same-output) but `++i` may be faster and never slower than `i++` for simple types.

If you have a C++11 compiler then you can:

- Use a range-based for loop and write

  ```
  for (const auto& filter : m_filters) {
      filterResult = filter.execute();
      if (filterResult.isEmpty()) break;
  }
  ```
- Initialize `m_filters` with a `std::initializer_list` directly in the [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

  ```
  FiltersSequence::FiltersSequence()
      : m_filters{Filter1(), Filter2(), Filter3()}
  {}
  ```

  Note that this also makes the order of the elements clear to the user.

Let me know in the comments if you have any further questions or need some elaboration on my comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I use the C++11, so I will do the updates linked to it. Shall I remove also the empty ctor (if no other intentions were taken in consideration, like no implicit copyctor, etc)?

Comment: And another question linked to the destructors: what if the `IFilter` has a virtual destructor?

Comment: @sop, I'm glad it helped. Yes, you can safely remove an empty constructor and the compiler will generate one for you. The [rule of three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) will help you in this kind of decision making. The use of virtual destructors is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors). The implicitly defined destructor of `FilterSequence` will call the destructor of `std::vector<Ifilter>` which in turn will call the destructor of `Ifilter` (virtual or not).

Comment: I am sorry about this, but I have not managed to make it run :D. It needs to be pointer of `IFilter`. Using `shared_ptr` leads to error because of the pure abstract `execute(filterResult)`. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you post a sample that compiles with an [online compiler](http://ideone.com/) then I might be able to find the bug. That is, I need to see the remaining code to help you out with specific details.

Comment: I figured it out, sorry

Answer (score 1):

> I thought of something like having a map< std::string, IFilter > for
>   being sure that the sequence is in the order that I want. What do you
>   think of this?

`std::map` for such simple case should be avoided. `std::map` would be more appropriate if you are not sure that your `IFilter` objects could be inserted in any order by client code and you do have lots of entry. Of course we should measure our program performance by both(.i.e. `std::vector` or `std::map`

> Is it good enough? Or this is just making it more complicated and I
>   need just to pay attention at push_back.

**Yes**, it look ok. We should always use more simpler/efficient data structure(`std::vector`) as our default container unless we have valid reason to do otherwise.

```
BTW, is this going to call them in right order (1, 2, 3)?
```

**No**, It would be in order of (3,2,1) as `std::vector` would `push_back`. We can see that documentation clearly mention like this about `push_back`

```
Appends the given element value to the end of the container.
```

> ```
> [Filter3()][Filter2()][Filter1()]
>    0           1          2
> ```

Comment: I think the last YES should be a NO, I have verified and it seems that std::vector is like first in on first index, so the order is `Filter3`, `Filter2`, `Filter1` (3, 2, 1). Or is it dependent on the compilator?

Comment: @sop: Sorry it was my mistake and you are correct. My mistake. I have updated it my post.

Comment: No worry, but I have accepted the other answer.

Comment: @sop: Information should be correct as it may be refereed by others in future. Hence I corrected. :)